# ~てからでなければ vs ～なければ

Tags: grammar, nuances, conditionals

I'm learning the ～てからでなければ... grammar pattern, which my textbook defines as:

```
Until/unless ~ happens or is done, ... cannot happen or be done either. Used in negating or negative statements.
```

One of the practice problems is as follows (pick the best answer):

```
４時に（　　）飛行機の時間には間に合わない。
```

A: 起きなければ

or

B: 起きてからでなければ

The answer key says A is correct, but I don't understand why. Is there something grammatically wrong with B or is there a semantic nuance difference?

Comment: Try the answer here: http://lang-8.com/1018769/journals/45864111343768955588760617501620031184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Until/unless ~ happens or is done, ... cannot happen or be done either. Used in negating or negative statements.

I agree with the definition of ～てからでなければ in this sentence.

**４時に起きてからでなければ飛行機の時間には間に合わない。**

*Until/unless you wake up at 4 o'clock, you cannot arrive the time of departure of flight.*

This is a weird situation isn't it? If you wake up before 4 o'clock say at 3 o'clock, will you miss the flight?

**４時に起きなければ飛行機の時間には間に合わない。**

So, this is conditional sentence.

*If you don't wake up at 4 o'clock, you will miss the flight. ⇨ If you wake up before 4 o'clock, you can get on the flight.*